# Whats the use of UIControlState "application" of UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrolstate

I went through the [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate/1618214-application) too but it just states that its

> Additional control-state flags available for application use.

Its just a getter method so when does it get set?

Comment: I think your question body+title is a bit misleading since the `UIControlState.application` is not at all specific to `UIButton`, and it is not a method either. Are you asking what the use of `UIControlState.application` is and at what time the `state` property of any UI-element assumes the `.application` value?

Comment: see this :https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate

Comment: @KKRocks I think OP saw that already since the sentence quoted is exactly the same.

Answer (score 11):

`application` and `reserved` are basically markers. That is more clear when looking at the objective-c documentation for them:

[disabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate/uicontrolstatedisabled): `UIControlStateDisabled = 1 << 1`

[application](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate/uicontrolstateapplication?language=objc): `UIControlStateApplication = 0x00FF0000`

[reserved](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate/uicontrolstatereserved?language=objc): `UIControlStateReserved = 0xFF000000`

That means that the second least significant bit of a `UIControlState` for example is responsible for determining wether or not a `UIControl` is disabled or not. All the bits from `17 - 24` (from `1 << 16` until `1 << 23`) are there for your application to use while `25 - 32` (from `1 << 24` until `1 << 31`) are there for internal frameworks to use.

That basically means that Apple is able / allowed to define new state flags of controls while using the lowest 16 bits, you have the guarantee to be able to use 8 bits for custom flags of your own.

Defining custom flags can be done e.g. via:

```
let myFlag = UIControlState(rawValue: 1 << 18)

class MyButton : UIButton {
    var customFlags = myFlag
    override var state: UIControlState {
        get {
            return [super.state, customFlags]
        }
    }

    func disableCustom() {
        customFlags.remove(myFlag)
    }
}
```

which can be used via

```
let myButton = MyButton()
print(myButton.state.rawValue) // 262144 (= 2^18)
myButton.isEnabled = false
myButton.isSelected = true
print(myButton.state.rawValue) // 262150 (= 262144 + 4 + 2)
myButton.disableCustom()
print(myButton.state.rawValue) // 6 (= 4 + 2)
```

Comment: Your override var looks like it returns an array of UIControlState yet it returns a UIControlState with the state and customFlags XOR'ed together. How is this?

Comment: @Brynjar https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-option-sets/ - they conform to [`ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyarrayliteral)

Comment: @Brynjar and it does not work like `XOR`, it is a bitwise `OR` or simply a `+` since no single bit is `1` in two different flags.

Comment: Thx. Ole's blog is always good. Ok sure, a bitwise OR, that said XOR would return the same result ; )