# Overriding isHighlighted still changes UIControlState - why?

Tags: swift, uicontrol, uicontrolstate

In a `UIControl`, if I override `isHighlighted` to set a private `_isHighlighted` property, and then check the control's `state` to see if it contains `.highlighted`, the state still accurately reflects the change. See code below.

My question is, how is this possible? I never call `super.isHighlighted` or manipulate the state property. `state` is an `OptionSet` that must have the `.highlighted` property inserted into the set, which, from what I can determine, does not, or should not, happen if I override the property.

The only other explanation I can think of is that `state` is actually a computed property based off other properties (i.e. `isSelected`, `isEnabled`, etc.)

```
class MyControl: UIControl {

    private var _isHighlighted: Bool = false

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get { return self._isHighlighted }
        set { self._isHighlighted = newValue }
    }

}


let myControl = MyControl()
myControl.isHighlighted = true
myControl.state.contains(.highlighted) // returns true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only other explanation I can think of is that state is actually a computed property based off other properties (i.e. isSelected, isEnabled, etc.)

Good explanation! Let's try logging (printing) in the getter to see if that's true:

```
class MyControl: UIControl {
    private var _isHighlighted: Bool = false
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        get { print("getting"); return self._isHighlighted }
        set { self._isHighlighted = newValue }
    }
}
let myControl = MyControl()
myControl.isHighlighted = true
print("about to check state")
myControl.state.contains(.highlighted)
print("checked state")
```

And here's the log:

```
about to check state
getting
checked state
```

Quod erat demonstrandum.

Comment: Yes. Interesting. This has implications for trying to implement my own custom states (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856042/can-i-use-custom-values-of-uicontrolstate-for-my-own-control). Which I am indeed doing. Looks like there is no real need for a custom state bit mask on top of state! Yikes. I think I need to change a bunch of code :-(